# Accept cooldown shows times in past tense

Tags: bug, status-completed, time

I'm an impatient person, so when frantically trying to accept an answer, I came across this:

[image: Red circles don't show up well on a red background]

Did you mean 'in a moment'?

Comment: the problem with that statement isn't the circled part, the problem is "can" should be "can't."

Comment: @Ryathal Or maybe it's missing an ellipsis: "You can accept an answer just ... *now*"

Comment: `HH:MM:SS` might be a more informative message. But what fun is _that_?

Comment: @TimPost Without a clock it's not really informative. Would be nice if there *was* a clock somewhere in the top bar.

Comment: A BoltClock....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next build we won't show the "just now" text for this case, yay optional parameters.

Comment: So is it just going to say "You can accept an answer"?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - It'd be "in 1 second" in this case

Answer (score 1):

This is just the `You can accept an answer in <number> <unit of time>` message, except SO uses the phrase "just now" to denote time spans less than a few seconds.

It works when we're looking at how long ago something was posted, but fails here. I bet you can find the same problem anywhere a `span.relativetime` is used to indicate a timespan between now and a point in the future.